# Layout for tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

The attached layout which works correctly for a phone (Samsung Infuse), but it does not show 
layout correctly when the app is uploaded  to a tablet (Nexus 7). The button sizing is incorrect. How can I fix this?

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/"
            style="@string/menu_settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gecko25"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/link1_btn"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="58dip"
            android:minWidth="98dip"
            android:text="About"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/link2_btn"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="58dip"
            android:minWidth="98dip"
            android:text="Experience"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/link3_btn"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="58dip"
            android:minWidth="98dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="Bulacards"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How it will be good for tablet also?  you are giving static height-width to the button. Please follow the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You can also define dimension.xml for each size, since looks like you only have a few do values. So you use `@dimen/button_height` where you currently have 58dip and set different values for each size.

Comment: use layout weight for dividing space equally between all buttons

Answer (score 0):

Make different layouts for different densities. ie, place the same xml file in 
`layout-hdpi`,
`layout-xhdpi`,
`layout-tvdpi`

To create those folders in res/layout follow these steps:

Right click on layout folder --> new-->other-->Andorid xml layout-->next-->give the filename(must be same in all densities)-->AvailableQulaifiers tab select density--> move it to chosen qualifiers with the help of arrow in between--> there select for what density (medium high tv)--->finish

Like for example:

*Nexus S* and *Nexus one* ---> `hdpi`

*Galaxy Nexus* ----> `xhdpi`

*Nexus 7* ---> `tvdpi`

and give `heights` and `widths` for the `Button`.. best practice is to set them to `wrapcontent` , if for your scenario it requires height follow the above steps. and give height and width such that different for phone and tablets which comes under different **densities**

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you use tvdpi for Nexus 7 screens.

See this:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html

Probably the best way to detect 7" tablets (like the Nexus 7) is to use the qualifier:

layout-sw600dp

And the qualifier for 10" tablets:

layout-sw720dp

You might want to try specifying the button sizes in sp rather than dp as they may need to bigger or smaller if the user changes the default font size but wrap_content and/or use weights are usually best.